# trouble Linq to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

This is my DB (part of it):

```
Vehicule table :
Matv string primary ;
cCode int foreign key references city,
// some other columns
Indisponible(unavailable) table:
idin int primary,
from date 
to date
idv string foreign key references Matv in vehicule table.
```

One vehicule can have many unavailable dates.

This is my search method:

```
        public ActionResult search(int citycode, string from, string to)
        {
            DateTime dd1 = Convert.ToDateTime(from);
            DateTime df1 = Convert.ToDateTime(to);
            var model = (from p in entity.vehicule
                         join y in entity.indisponible on p.Matv equals y.idv
                         where p.cCode == citycode && ( dd1 > y.Df && df1 < y.Dd )
                         select p).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
```

This search query will allow me to find all avaible cars in the city between to the dates `from` and `to`.
So to do this i have to check that the date chosen by the user is not in the unavailable table. 
For example this car is unvailable

> From 01/04/201  to 26/04/2012 and From 01/05/2012  to 09/05/2012.

So if user make search From 28/04/2012 to 30/04/2012 this car has to be shown 
Else if he make search From 28/04/2012 to 03/05/2012 this car will not be showed in search result.

But something is wrong, it never shows any results. Can anyone help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `where` applies to each row.  It cannot consider multiple rows at the same time to determine availability.  But it should... any indisponible record that is in our range should filter the car completely.

This might be closer to what you want:

```
from p in entity.vehicule
where p.cCode == citycode
where p.indisponibles.All(y => y.Df < dd1 || df1 < y.Dd)
select p
```

All returns true if every record meets that criteria and it returns true when the source is empty.

An indisponible record shouldn't filter our car if if starts after our range or if it ends before our range.  If all the indisponible records are such, then we keep the car.

Comment: this dosn't work, in sql this part `( dd1 > y.Df && df1 < y.Dd ) ` should look like this `not between(y.Dd,y.Df )&& df1 not between(y.Dd,y.Df )`

Comment: I didn't use &&.  Our logic yields the same result but mine is simpler to read.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to give u feedback but instead u can ask in steand voting down for me :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here: does `Df` mean "Date Fin" and `Dd` mean "Date Debut"?  If so, your query is looking for items that come *after the end* and *before the beginning* of your date range.

You probably want something like this:

```
dd1 < y.Df && df1 > y.Dd
```

#### Update

If you want to include only dates that are outside the given range, you want dates that are *either* before the start date *or* after the end date:

```
dd1 > y.Df || df1 < y.Dd
```

Comment: Yes it means "Date debut et fin" But this date is for unavailable so if the date chosen by user is in uvailable date it hasn't to be showen. can u check my post i have update it.

Comment: Something like this in sql `( dd1 not between(y.Dd,y.Df )&& df1 not between(y.Dd,y.Df )`.

Comment: look in sql my command should look like this : `!(dd1 Not Between Date(y.dd) And Date(y.dF)) OR (df1 Not Between Date(y.dd) And Date(y.df))`. so can tell me how to write in linw to sql

Answer (score 1):

Sloved in this way :

```
from p in entity.vehicule                        
                         where p.agence.idgov == idv
                         where !p.indisponible.Any(b => (dd1 >= b.Dd && dd1 <= b.Df) || (df1 >= b.Dd && df1 <= b.Df))
                         where !p.indisponible.Any(c => (c.Dd >= dd1 && c.Dd <= df1) || (c.Df >= dd1 && c.Df <= df1))
                         select p).ToList();
```

Thanks all for your help.